# boost bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target when converting a string to unsigned long long

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast, boost-lexicalcast

the following piece of code that I compiled on [wandbox.org](https://wandbox.org/) is causing the following error. I don't understand why I am getting the error.

```
// This file is a "Hello, world!" in C++ language by GCC for wandbox.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"

typedef unsigned  long long Ulonglong ; 

int main()
{

    Ulonglong result   = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned long long>("862.00");
    return 0;
}
```

> Start prog.cc: In function 'int main()': prog.cc:11:15: warning:
>   unused variable 'result' [-Wunused-variable]    11 |     Ulonglong
>   result        = boost::lexical_cast("862.00");
>         |               ^~~~~~ terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept'   what(): 
>   bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
>   Aborted Finish

Comment: 862.00 is a floating point number, not integer.

Comment: @vll so lexical_cast is different from atol? I cannot use atol because a reviewer told me it's not safe and suggested lexical_cast. we are not using C++11 neither

Comment: Your wandbox link doesn't show your snippet.

Comment: My guess is that lexical_cast ensures that all the input was consumed during conversion. Which is not the case. ".00" will remain in the input buffer after conversion which causes an error.

Comment: @gringo That is correct; atol ignores errors, including this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `boost::lexical_cast` must perform an exact conversion, with no extended behaviour. You are trying to cast a string representation of a number containing a decimal point (thus containing a fractional part) to an integer, which is not allowed.

You should either first convert to float/double (mind the data loss for very large integers) and then convert to integer, or cut off the decimal part of the string before handing it off to `boost::lexical_cast`.

Comment: FWIW, `13` is also a decimal number - a number represented in base 10. It's the decimal separator that is the problem.